# In Uno, is there a penalty for playing out of turn?

Tags: uno

Uno rules state that:

> If a player plays a wrong card and it is noticed by any other player, he/she must take the card back and take two extra cards from the DRAW pile. Play continues with the next player in turn.

As I understand it, this penalty applies when a player plays a wrong card during HER turn. What about when a player plays a VALID card OUT of her turn because she thought it was her turn to play?

How do you interpret this penalty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This irregularity of play is not covered by the rules. It's up to your group  to make a judgment/correction. The most obvious correction is to just have them pick up the played-out-of-turn card and continue. But if your group agrees, imposing the stock penalty of "and draw two cards" to every irregularity is also fine.

Note also the stock rules at https://www.unorules.com/ don't include any rules for handling any misplays.

Comment: So, in your opinion, the rule I quoted above was only meant for players playing a wrong card during their turn, not for players who play a card out of turn?

Comment: Indeed. The wording clearly assumes it is the player's turn. "wrong card" not "wrong order". Also, the "play continues with the next player in turn" would skip some innocent bystander if the quoted rule were applied to out-of-order plays.

Comment: The logical extension of a "stock penalty for every irregularity" with the base rules of Uno is the game [Mao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mao_(card_game))